# Salesforce: How to notify a user

Tags: salesforce

I need to notify a user on a Scheduled Apex. How can I send an email to a user or some other form or notification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the email classes available for apex [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_email_outbound.htm).

```
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
String[] toAddresses = new String[] {'user@acme.com'}; 
String[] ccAddresses = new String[] {'smith@gmail.com'};
mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
mail.setCcAddresses(ccAddresses);
mail.setReplyTo('support@acme.com');
mail.setSenderDisplayName('Salesforce Support');
mail.setSubject('New Case Created : ' + case.Id);
mail.setBccSender(false);    
mail.setUseSignature(false);    
mail.setPlainTextBody('Your Case: ' + case.Id +' has been created.');
mail.setHtmlBody('Your case:<b> ' + case.Id +' </b>has been created.<p>'+
     'To view your case <a href=https://na1.salesforce.com/'+case.Id+'>click here.</a>');
Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
```